# remove a row from a list

Tags: c#, list

i have a datagrid which produces a table
`ID|Name|Category|Description|Quantity`
a user can edit the column Quantity to update product quantity, though there is a button at the end so it can do multiple updating rather than one row at a time, i have the code

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
 private void Updatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveRows();//save to sql ect
        ClearRows();//empty the list
    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       //getvalues correspoding to ProductID and Quantity for the row thats been changed
        AddRow(ProductID, Quantity);
    }

public void AddRow(int ProductID, int quantity)
    {
        duplicate(ProductID);        
        products.Add(new Product { ID = ProductID, Quantity = quantity });
    }

    public void duplicate(int ProductID)
    {          
        foreach (var row in products)
        {
            if (row.ID == ProductID)
            {                  
                products.Remove(new Product() { ID = ProductID });
            }
        }
    }
```

for some reasons the row does not want to be removed ie 
`product id 1 quantity 5
product id 2 quantity 3 then i change the row
product id 1 to quantity 6`

it wont remove the duplicate ive tried different combination but with no success. ive heard about hashset on the internet but not something ive learnt yet, so it must be with list

Comment: I can't see why you would remove an existing item and then add a new one rather than just updating the exiting one but, assuming that that is what you want to do, you can't remove items from a list in a `foreach` loop.  You should use a `for` loop and either `break` out after finding a match or, if you want to potentially remove multiple items, loop backwards.

Comment: Also, how is "duplicate" a good name for that method?  What it does is remove a duplicate so any sensible name must reflect that.

Comment: I doubt you approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a 'new object' from a list.  You have to remove the actual object, or store the object to remove it later.

I'd recommend Linq for ease of use.  Forgive me, my C# is a bit rusty.

```
public void duplicate(int ProductID)
{          
    products = products.Where(x => x.ID != ProductID).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  public void UpdateProductQuantity(int productID, int quantity)
  {
       product = products.Where(x => x.ID == productID).FirstOrDefault();
       if(product != null)
       {
         product.Quantity = quantity;
       }
  }
```

In AddRow(), just call this.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your approach but still if you want to do this then solution is:

```
public void duplicate(int ProductID)
{                                         
    products.ToList().Remove(products.Where(a=>a.ID == ProductID).FirstOrDefault());
}
```